# how to code sap.m.sample.ListGrouping by using js view in openui5

Tags: sapui5

hi i need List grouping control by using js view.but openui5 provides code by using xml view.
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.ListGrouping/preview
how to convert this code into js view and how to make ListGrouping able to selection for both element level and group level and change this as dropdown box

List.view.xml

```
 <mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.m.sample.ListGrouping.List"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <List
        items="{
            path: '/ProductCollection',
            sorter: {
                path: 'SupplierName',
                descending: false,
                group: true
            },
            groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeader'
        }"
        headerText="Products" >
        <StandardListItem
            title="{Name}"
            description="{ProductId}"
            icon="{ProductPicUrl}"
            iconDensityAware="false"
            iconInset="false" />
    </List>
</mvc:View>
```

List.controller.js

```
   sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
    ], function(jQuery, GroupHeaderListItem, Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    var ListController = Controller.extend("sap.m.sample.ListGrouping.List", {

        onInit : function (evt) {
            // set explored app's demo model on this sample
            var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap.ui.demo.mock", "/products.json"));
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
        },

        getGroupHeader: function (oGroup){
            return new GroupHeaderListItem( {
                title: oGroup.key,
                upperCase: false
            } );
        }
    });


    return ListController;

});
```

how to write the same code by using js view
I have tried like as follows, but i am getting Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element sap.m.List#__list0 !
List.view.js

```
sap.ui.jsview("oui5mvc.List", {
    getControllerName : function() {
        return "oui5mvc.List";
    },
    createContent : function(oController) {
        odbbshiftGlobalId = this.getId();
        var oMyFlexbox = new sap.m.FlexBox({
              items: [
                      oList = new sap.m.List({
                            width: '500px',
                            group: true,
                            groupHeaderFactory: '.getGroupHeader',
                            items: [

                            ]
                          }),
          ]
            });
        oMyFlexbox.placeAt(this.getId()).addStyleClass("tes");
    }

});
```

List.controller.js

```
sap.ui.controller("oui5mvc.List", {

    onInit: function() {
          var data = {
                    "ProductCollection": [
                                        {
                                            "ProductId": "1239102",
                                            "Name": "Power Projector 4713",
                                            "Category": "Projector",
                                            "SupplierName": "Titanium",
                                            "Description": "A very powerful projector with special features for Internet usability, USB",
                                            "WeightMeasure": 1467,
                                            "WeightUnit": "g",
                                            "Price": 856.49,
                                            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
                                            "Status": "Available",
                                            "Quantity": 3,
                                            "UoM": "PC",
                                            "Width": 51,
                                            "Depth": 42,
                                            "Height": 18,
                                            "DimUnit": "cm",
                                            "ProductPicUrl": "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-6100.jpg"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "ProductId": "2212-121-828",
                                            "Name": "Gladiator MX",
                                            "Category": "Graphics Card",
                                            "SupplierName": "Technocom",
                                            "Description": "Gladiator MX: DDR2 RoHS 128MB Supporting 512MB Clock rate: 350 MHz Memory Clock: 533 MHz, Bus Type: PCI-Express, Memory Type: DDR2 Memory Bus: 32-bit Highlighted Features: DVI Out, TV Out , HDTV",
                                            "WeightMeasure": 321,
                                            "WeightUnit": "g",
                                            "Price": 81.7,
                                            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
                                            "Status": "Discontinued",
                                            "Quantity": 10,
                                            "UoM": "PC",
                                            "Width": 34,
                                            "Depth": 14,
                                            "Height": 2,
                                            "DimUnit": "cm",
                                            "ProductPicUrl": "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1071.jpg"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "ProductId": "K47322.1",
                                            "Name": "Hurricane GX",
                                            "Category": "Graphics Card",
                                            "SupplierName": "Red Point Stores",
                                            "Description": "Hurricane GX: DDR2 RoHS 512MB Supporting 1024MB Clock rate: 550 MHz Memory Clock: 933 MHz, Bus Type: PCI-Express, Memory Type: DDR2 Memory Bus: 64-bit Highlighted Features: DVI Out, TV-In, TV-Out, HDTV",
                                            "WeightMeasure": 588,
                                            "WeightUnit": "g",
                                            "Price": 219,
                                            "CurrencyCode": "EUR",
                                            "Status": "Out of Stock",
                                            "Quantity": 25,
                                            "UoM": "PC",
                                            "Width": 34,
                                            "Depth": 14,
                                            "Height": 2,
                                            "DimUnit": "cm",
                                            "ProductPicUrl": "https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/img/HT-1072.jpg"
                                        },

                                    ],
                                    "ProductCollectionStats": {
                                        "Counts": {
                                            "Total": 14,
                                            "Weight": {
                                                "Ok": 7,
                                                "Heavy": 5,
                                                "Overweight": 2
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "Groups": {
                                            "Category": {
                                                "Projector": 1,
                                                "Graphics Card": 2,
                                                "Accessory": 4,
                                                "Printer": 2,
                                                "Monitor": 3,
                                                "Laptop": 1,
                                                "Keyboard": 1
                                            },
                                            "SupplierName": {
                                                "Titanium": 3,
                                                "Technocom": 3,
                                                "Red Point Stores": 5,
                                                "Very Best Screens": 3
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "Filters": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "Category",
                                                "values": [
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Projector",
                                                        "data": 1
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Graphics Card",
                                                        "data": 2
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Accessory",
                                                        "data": 4
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Printer",
                                                        "data": 2
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Monitor",
                                                        "data": 3
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Laptop",
                                                        "data": 1
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Keyboard",
                                                        "data": 1
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "type": "SupplierName",
                                                "values": [
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Titanium",
                                                        "data": 3
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Technocom",
                                                        "data": 3
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Red Point Stores",
                                                        "data": 5
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "text": "Very Best Screens",
                                                        "data": 3
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                  };



              var oTemplate11 = new sap.m.StandardListItem({title : "{Name}"});
              oList.setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(data));
              oList.bindItems("/ProductCollection");
              oList.placeAt('content');

    },
    getGroupHeader: function (oGroup){
        return new sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem( {
            title: oGroup.key,
            upperCase: false
        });
    }, 

});
```

Comment: Hi hirse i have tried to write it by using js view and i updated my question.please check and help me to fix

Answer (score 0):

Your call to bind items to the list is not entirely correct.
The method takes an object with binding information as parameter instead of just the path to the model property. See the documentation for [`bindItems`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#bindItems) and [`bindAggregation`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation) in general.

In your case it should look like

```js
oList.bindItems({
  path: "/ProductCollection",
  template: new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: "{Name}",
    description: "{ProductId}",
    icon: "{ProductPicUrl}"
  })
});
```

Comment: hi hirse i added code like as you suggest data is binding but grouping is not formed